# django db settings into a .env file with decouple

Tags: django, decoupling, python-decouple

I want to put my django database settings into a .env file for production.

While I successfully wrote `SECRET KEY` and `DEBUG` in my .env file, when I try to do the same thing for my database settings, I get an error in the webapp.

Here is the way I went about it:

```
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)

DATABASE_ENGINE ='django_tenants.postgresql_backend'
DATABASE_NAME = config('DATABASE_NAME')
DATABASE_USER = config('DATABASE_USER')
DATABASE_PASSWORD = config('DATABASE_PASSWORD')
DATABASE_HOST = config('DATABASE_HOST', cast=db_url)
DATABASE_PORT = config('PORT', cast=int)
```

and in my .env file

```
SECRET_KEY = supersecretkey
DEBUG = False

DATABASE_NAME = mydb
DATABASE_USER = me
DATABASE_PASSWORD = greatpassword
DATABASE_HOST =urlurl
DATABASE_PORT = 5432
```

Previously I had my db settings written as such and everything was working great:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
         'NAME': 'mydb',
         'USER': 'me',
         'PASSWORD' : 'greatpassword',
         'HOST': 'urlurl',
         'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have tried the following structure in settings.py thanks to the comments, but still get the same error:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': config('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD' : config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'config('DATABASE_HOST', cast=db_url),
        'PORT': config('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Django's log is outputing this but I can't really see how it relates to the issue at hand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [redirect_to] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: '3UKtg6BF5E1qXSTE8nlEevd4e4jVZMcgpdx5W0NZIrB18yuOoCJqnW7xxc7WBfyG'>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fa6a25$
```

Comment: Are you using `config` from the `python-decouple` package?

Comment: yes, i found a way to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define your `DATABASES` setting as a dictionary:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': config('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD' : config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your advice, unfortunately it stills output the same ```502 bad gateway error```

Comment: @Peyo Do you have a traceback from your Django logs?

Comment: @Peyo it should be `DATABASE_PORT` rather than `PORT` right? Updated the code with the correct env var

Comment: I have tried with ```DATABASE_PORT``` and still the same issue. The logs tell me that a template variable could not be found, which seems to come from a wsgi get request. I''ll update my post to show

Answer (score 0):

#You should not decouple ENGINE and USER, at least not if you are using a custom postgresql role.

#Solution:

#############################

from decouple import config

```
dbname = config('NAME')
dbpassword = config('PASSWORD')
dbhost = config('HOST')
dbport = config('PORT')

DATABASES = {

'default': {

    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

    'NAME': dbname,

    'USER': 'yourusername',

    'PASSWORD': dbpassword,

    'HOST': dbhost, 

    'PORT': dbport,
   }
}
```

#############################

#if you create a custom role, then you have to also add user (yourusername) with the same name to your server

#Port is normally 5432 or just leave it empty.